# Reboot when there is a hardware failure without physical access to machine?

Tags: linux, command-line, reboot

I'm getting this error message whathever I do:

```
$ sudo reboot
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Input/output error
$ reboot
bash: /sbin/reboot: Input/output error
```

It's a hardware failure according to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86363/bash-usr-sbin-useradd-input-output-error-what-does-this-mean). Is there anyway that I can reboot the machine without physically pull the the plug. The machine is not close to me. I can SSH into the machine. `ls`, `pwd`, `echo`, `cat` and some other apps are working. Things like `ps`, `vim` and `killall` are not working.

Comment: What commands can you use? Can you become `root`? All solutions will require root access so if you can't run `sudo`, can you at least `su`? Can you run `shutdown`? How about `init`?

Comment: No, I can't be `root`. I didn't set Ubuntu's root password! :(

Comment: @Mohsen Setting a root password would not make any difference. You'd have to run `su` instead of `sudo`, but you'd run into the same problem. If you have no way to gain root access, you cannot reboot.

Answer (score 8):

If you have root access, you can try to do this:

```
# echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

(that will immediately reboot the system without syncing or unmounting your disks.)

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a way to reboot without root privileges.